# Automatically restore the local disk at every boot

Tags: windows, windows-vista, restore

How can you automatically restore all changes made to an installation of Windows Vista  (including all created files) from an image or something similar at every boot, but only for a normal user account (as in, not an administrator)? I was hoping to do this so as to protect the installation from bad changes made by these normal users.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10837

Comment: How this tool restore that image automatic on every boot without ask the user or something ..

Comment: Why not use a VM?

Comment: This is what internet cafés do. Why not have a chat with them about what software they use?

Comment: @G3org3 Let's start from scratch. This machine is in a domain or local machine home?

Comment: i don't know ... it's a simple PC connected to a router AFH understand what i'm searching for but i don't want to ask any of them ...